# Dplyr summarise with multiple functions with parameters does not give desired result

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Using this function to make all summary functions use na.rm parameter `True`:

```r
    df %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, list(mean = ~mean(., na.rm = T), 
                                         sd = ~sd(., na.rm = T),
                                         median = ~median(., na.rm = T), 
                                         min = ~min(., na.rm = T), 
                                         max = ~max(., na.rm = T))) %>% t()
```

I would expect this to give something like this:

[image: Expected Result]

But instead it gives a 2 column data such as:

[image: Real result]

Why is this implemented as such? And is there an elegant solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the code below just a bit more efficient, since

1. you can call only once the na.rm argument ;
2. you only need one pivot operation.

> ```
> df %>%
>   summarise(across(is.numeric,
>                    list("mean" = mean,
>                         "sd" = sd,
>                         "median" = median,
>                         "min" = min,
>                         "max" = max),
>                    .names = "{.fn}_{.col}",
>                    na.rm = T)) %>%
>   pivot_longer(everything(),
>                names_sep = "_",
>                names_to = c(".value", "column"))
> ```

Comment: This works perfectly. Is `pivot_longer` really necessary though? I believe this should have been easier. And if i add a function that does not use `na.rm` then it raises `unused argument` error :(

Comment: Yes, that's because the  na.rm argument is used for every function of the list. If you want to use a function without this arg, just use the syntax you choosed in the first time. Regarding the pivot_longer, I think it's hard to do without, at least with a tidyverse syntax. Maybe you could try something with the "rowwise" function, but is it really better?

Answer (score 0):

Using this kind of code fixes the issue but is not elegant whatsoever.

```r
df %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, list(mean = ~mean(., na.rm = T), 
                                      sd = ~sd(., na.rm = T),
                                      median = ~median(., na.rm = T), 
                                      min = ~min(., na.rm = T), 
                                      max = ~max(., na.rm = T)))) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "func", values_to = "value") %>% 
  separate(col = func, into = c("column", "function_type"), sep = "_") %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = column, values_from = value, names_from = function_type)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea. Clearly the end result leaves a little to be desired (e.g., the column names).

I think one can make a data frame–friendly version of `t()`, but still using `pivot_longer()` and `pivot_wider()`; it is hard to avoid those functions.

```r
library(readr)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df <- read_csv(paste0("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cran/",
                      "rattle/master/inst/csv/weather.csv"),
               show_col_types = FALSE)

get_summary <- function(x) {
  list(mean = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), 
       sd = sd(x, na.rm = TRUE),
       median = median(x, na.rm = TRUE), 
       min = min(x, na.rm = TRUE), 
       max = max(x, na.rm = TRUE))
}

df |>
  reframe(across(where(is.numeric), get_summary)) |>
  t()
#>               [,1]     [,2]     [,3]    [,4]  [,5]  
#> MinTemp       7.265574 6.0258   7.45    -5.3  20.9  
#> MaxTemp       20.55027 6.690516 19.65   7.6   35.8  
#> Rainfall      1.428415 4.2258   0       0     39.8  
#> Evaporation   4.521858 2.669383 4.2     0.2   13.8  
#> Sunshine      7.909366 3.481517 8.6     0     13.6  
#> WindGustSpeed 39.84066 13.05981 39      13    98    
#> WindSpeed9am  9.651811 7.951929 7       0     41    
#> WindSpeed3pm  17.98634 8.856997 17      0     52    
#> Humidity9am   72.03552 13.13706 72      36    99    
#> Humidity3pm   44.51913 16.85095 43      13    96    
#> Pressure9am   1019.709 6.686212 1020.15 996.5 1035.7
#> Pressure3pm   1016.81  6.469422 1017.4  996.8 1033.2
#> Cloud9am      3.89071  2.956131 3.5     0     8     
#> Cloud3pm      4.02459  2.666268 4       0     8     
#> Temp9am       12.35847 5.630832 12.55   0.1   24.7  
#> Temp3pm       19.23087 6.640346 18.55   5.1   34.5  
#> RISK_MM       1.428415 4.2258   0       0     39.8
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>